# Caja-dropbox with "bind --mount" doesn't automatically sync

Tags: mount, ubuntu-mate, caja

I want to use `mount --bind` to link to different locations on my filesystem for syncing with Dropbox as symlinks are no longer supported:

`mount --bind ~/Documents ~/Dropbox/Documents`

I expected that files would be automatically uploaded to Dropbox like any other file.

Files created in mounted location are flagged as "syncing" and looking at the Dropbox indicator, there is an option to "Pause Syncing"

[image]

[image]

If I "Pause Syncing" and then "Resume Syncing", then files are uploaded immediately.

Steps to reproduce the behaviour:

1. `mount --bind ~/Documents ~/Dropbox/Documents`
2. Add `test.txt` to ~/Documents (or directly in ~/Dropbox/Documents - same result)
3. Check flag and status of sync in applet

This feels like a bug but wondered if anyone had come across this before and has a solution?

Comment: The Dropbox has its proprietary binary component. I think we can't do anything with it. Will simple symlink (`ln -s`) work for you?

Comment: Is this mount bind executed before the dropbox daemon starts?

Comment: Mount point was created when caja-dropbox was running - simple restart of the service kicked it into action (Should have done this immediately!) Thank you!